# Hector querySuperColumns returns only partial super columns

Tags: cassandra, super-columns

I have the following code intending to grab over all the supercolumns for a key and then find a target data. but it turns out that it only return me partial super columns (for example - 100 out of 400). Is there any reason why and how to fix it?

```
        SuperCfResult<UUID, Long, UUID> superCfResult = sTemplate.querySuperColumns(key);
        Collection<Long> supercolumns = superCfResult.getSuperColumns();
```

Comment: Can you post the query itself?

Comment: I didn't do a query before the code above. what kind of query is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with the Hector template API, but the default unless you specify a count is typically 100, so you should try calling `sTemplate.setCount()` and specifying a higher value--possibly `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.